# I installed xen-hypervisor and it breaks bootup

Tags: boot, grub2, xen

I ran some aptitude install commands for xen and xen tools and its broken grub,  it hangs indefinitely when I boot.

This unanswered question happens.

[booting xen hypervisor on ubuntu14.04 stuck at loading initial ramdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868968/booting-xen-hypervisor-on-ubuntu14-04-stuck-at-loading-initial-ramdisk)

Took me a while to discover that typing ESC once at exactly the rigth moment gets me a boot menu that lets me choose a kernel that works.

This is kinda not cool :)

Is there anyway you can undo what XEN does to grub.

The contents of /etc/default/grub don't include the list of borked options.

/boot/grub/grub.cfg is over 1000 lines ling these days and looks to be very much not user editable and claims not to be.

The files in /etc/grub.d look pretty much non-user editable shell code too.

Can I delete 20_linux_xen for example?

The contents of /boot/grub are no longer self-explanatory.

Comment: I my case the boot menu appeared but XEN was now the default .. then it hang at "loading initial ramdisk" but afterwards my Laptop T470s did not start again. After (re)plugging it to power the LED blinked 3 times - nothing else happend. Luckily the "Emergency-reset hole" https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/pd104682 made my laptop bootable again

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
XEN_OVERRIDE_GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

in

```
/etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg
```

Does not remove xen options from grub but it stops them always being the default which is what seems to break boot-up.